# I need a word or a phrase to call someone an idiot, but with good humor

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It's so easy to do in a chat room. I just do this: [click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acI12jO0HSQ).

I want to capture that same benign, eye rolling, gently mocking disdain - but I have to stick to small words.

An example of an actual circumstance (true story) after which I might want to use such a phrase or word is when he ever-so-patiently explained to me that "rocket surgery" was an incorrect use of idiom.

Perhaps a quote?

I realize that this question is *at least* borderline for the site. If you feel I've crossed that line please edit if you feel that the question is salvageable.

EDIT: He's 56. Perhaps an instantly recognizable (to an American of his age) quote from pop-culture? Kind of like the way I might say, "Laugh it up, Fuzzball" to someone my age (46) who is very much enjoying the fact he's winning a card game?

Comment: That's something that encapsulates your whole personality. You naturally cannot use borrowed-wisdom in that department. (I expect a rejoinder any moment ;)

Comment: @Kris He doesn't need to know it's borrowed!

Comment: It would depend very much on how well I knew the target. There are some, mostly old colleagues, who I can call a 'pillock' with no offense taken whatever. But when speaking to a stranger it is an altogether different matter.

Comment: @WS2 This is a long-time acquaintance, almost friend. I say "almost" because he is sometimes such a pig-headed, sexist bigot that I can't stand to be around him - But then he *tries so hard* to be good that I end up tolerating him again, at least until next time. When I really am angry at him, I don't mince words - I let him have it. I don't need help with that, when I'm angry at him, he knows. I'm looking for something much more benign, especially for times like the "rocket surgery" correction, or when he assumes I can't screw in a light bulb because I'm a woman.

Comment: Think crotchety old-fart.

Comment: "Did you feel the breeze?"  "What breeze?"  "The breeze that joke made when it went right over your head."

Comment: @jim That's actually getting close. He's so dense about sarcasm that it's truly mind-boggling.

Comment: Surely if you know him that well, you can probably say anything with a smile to disarm it. It's the *way* it's said which makes it more benign: try saying "You pillock!" (to use WS2's expression) with a frown and then with a smile to see the difference. [PS: Actually your friend sounds rather like he is an Aspergers sufferer. I always say it's not we who suffer from that syndrome, is those around us. If it is the case, he may not recognise the frown/smile difference.]

Comment: @AndrewLeach I can and do "zing" him with a smiling shake of my head. I'm just running out of material!

Comment: "There are more brains in a chocolate mouse!" [Sir Geoffrey]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice! (especially considering our location)

Comment: 'Mouse', not 'moose'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth LOL...I read it as mousse!

Comment: Number than a frozen mukluk. // Hasn't got all his huskies on one leash. // One ski short of a snowmobile. // Three ice blocks shy of an igloo .

Answer (score 5):

You could say that he's *not the sharpest knife on the Christmas tree*

Comment: *'sharpest knife in the drawer'* and *'brightest bulb on the (Christmas) tree'* (in case anyone is unfamiliar with those idioms.)

Comment: I wish I had thought of that after the "rocket surgery" conversation! If I give it while maybe he'll forget so I can set him up to do it again. I'd use "chandelier" though, he's actually heard me use that one. "You're not the sharpest knife in the chandelier, are you?" I like it :) That will be epic if setting it up actually works. Dual layered mockery!

Comment: @Jolenealaska hah, good luck!